# Find first day per group where time spans midnight boundaries

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that calculates what hours a person has worked. We have a night team that logon anytime after 4PM and logoff before 8AM the following morning. The table looks like the below.

```
 Workdate      WorkHour
2018-11-13         20       -- this was the hour they logged on
2018-11-13         21
2018-11-13         22
2018-11-13         23
2018-11-14         0
2018-11-14         1
2018-11-14         2
2018-11-14         3
2018-11-14         4
2018-11-14         5        -- this was the hour they logged off
```

For the purpose of reporting, we only want to associate these hours worked to the date they first logged on, in this example the 13th of November 2018. My ideal output would look like the below.

```
Workdate      WorkHour    ReportingDate
2018-11-13         20      2018-11-13 
2018-11-13         21      2018-11-13 
2018-11-13         22      2018-11-13 
2018-11-13         23      2018-11-13 
2018-11-14         0       2018-11-13 
2018-11-14         1       2018-11-13 
2018-11-14         2       2018-11-13 
2018-11-14         3       2018-11-13 
2018-11-14         4       2018-11-13 
2018-11-14         5       2018-11-13
```

Any ideas on how I can do this? Appreciate any help

Jess

Comment: You're going to need to use a window function. Do you have a field that uniquely identifies one of the employees? Like a UserId?

Comment: Yep we have a userID and a Username field

Comment: Can we assume that a person never stays more than 23 hours?

Comment: This is correct

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it as a gaps and island problem where contiguous hours represent an island. You need to find all islands and find minimum date for each island:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (userid INT, workdate DATE, workhour INT);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, '2018-11-13', 20),
(1, '2018-11-13', 21),
(1, '2018-11-13', 22),
(1, '2018-11-13', 23),
(1, '2018-11-14',  0),
(1, '2018-11-14',  1),
(1, '2018-11-14',  2),
(1, '2018-11-14',  3),
(1, '2018-11-14',  4),
(1, '2018-11-14',  5),
(1, '2018-11-20', 6);

WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT userid, workdate, workhour
         , DATEADD(HOUR, workhour, CAST(workdate AS DATETIME)) AS workdatetime
    FROM @t
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT userid, workdate, workhour
         , CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, LAG(workdatetime) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY workdate, workhour), workdatetime) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS chg
    FROM cte1
), cte3 AS (
    SELECT userid, workdate, workhour
         , SUM(chg) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY workdate, workhour) AS grp
    FROM cte2
)
SELECT userid, workdate, workhour, MIN(workdate) OVER (PARTITION BY userid, grp) AS ReportingDate
FROM cte3
ORDER BY userid, workdate, workhour
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll update when I've got a working example, but try:

```
SELECT
MIN(WorkDate) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY WorkHour) [ReportingDate]
FROM <YourTable>
WHERE WorkDate >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

Comment: This will be a historical report so it might be run sometimes for a period in the past, ie last week.

Comment: Is there a shift ID or something that identifies a shift?

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of "gaps-and-islands".  You can identify the adjacent hours by subtracting an enumerated sequence.  After that, you just need to take the max over the group.

```
select t.*,
       min(workdate) over (partition by datediff(hour, - seqnum, workdatehour) as imputed_workdate
from (select t.*,
             dateadd(hour, workhour, workdate) as workdatehour,
             row_number() over (order by workdate, workhour) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: `datediff(day,` needs to be `dateadd(hour,`.